# Analyze groovy script with java

Tags: java, api, groovy

we have a large repository with hundreds of groovy scripts used by jenkins for a deployment job:

```
def CRON_CONDITION = 'H 1 * * *'
def PARAMS = [['key1','value1','description1'],
              ['key2','value2','description2']]
```

For a test case and reporting, I want to analyse these variables of each groovy script. Is it possible to parse that groovy script in java to get the declared values of the variables? I tried to read and parse the file in text mode line by line but its a weak concept.

Thanks for an answer!

Best regards
Davidge

Comment: You can execute groovy script fro java.

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to execute the groovy script, I want to analyze the source!

Comment: Well, then get ready to long ride. You need to write/find groovy parser and analyze parsing tree. It isn't that difficult, but may require some learning if you don't have expertise in this area.

Comment: Could you share one of the scripts and clarify what you want to detect. You could try to use http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/builder/AstBuilder.html to parse script to a tree and then analyse it.